# Update certificates in all instances of a VM scale set (service fabric)

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-keyvault, azure-vm-scale-set

I use Service Fabric in Azure and have an Azure VM scale set that is provisioned via a template and fetches all the required certificates from Azure Key Vault and installs the certificate into the certificate store of the instances.

Some certificates need to be renewed periodicaly, so I replace the certificate in the Key Vault with the new certificate. But how do I update the existing instances with the new certificates?

Do I need to re-image all instances or is there a better way to update the certificates?

Comment: Did you see these? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-security-update-certs-azure https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-rollover-cert-cn